# Display tag append query parameters to sort URL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am currently using displaytag with spring MVC like so:

```
 <display:table class="displayTag" name="${searchList}" requestURI="" sort="external">
       <display:column title="Name" property="name" href="viewInstitution.htm" paramId="institution" paramProperty="dbId" sortable="true">
 </display:table>
```

When hovering over the name column I get a link like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/institutionManagement.htm?sort=name&dir=desc
```

However I want to append some additional parameters to the URI, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/institutionManagement.htm?sort=name&dir=desc&parama=value&paramb=value
```

These are sent from the backend by spring, and I would want to append them to the end of every sort link.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use like this?

```
    <display:table class="displayTag" name="${searchList}" requestURI="" sort="external" id="row">
<display:column tittle="name">
    <a href="viewInstitution.htm?parama=<c:out value='${row.value1}'/>&paramb=<c:out value='${row.value2}'/> 
    <c:out value='${row.name}'/>
    </a>
</display:column>
     </display:table>
```

Comment: He wants them added to the column header link, not the row links.